# Why am I getting a compile error in my trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, campaign

**Background**

I'm looking to write an apex trigger that will look at newly created leads, and assign them to a campaign based on a custom field in the leads, but I'm getting stuck with this compile error.  What am I doing wrong?

Please be patient as this is my first apex trigger.

**Code**

```
trigger leadCampaignManager on Lead (after insert) {
    CampaignMember[] cms = new CampaignMember[0];
    for(Lead record:Trigger.new)
        if(!String.isBlank(record.trip_name__c)) {
            cms.add(new CampaignMember(LeadId=record.Id,CampaignId=campaigns.get(record.trip_name__c)));
        }
    insert cms;
}
```

**Save Error**

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: campaigns at line 5
>   column 68

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. For the record this questions is correctly being flagged as too broad by a lot of people. The best practice is to show what you've tried so far and where you've gotten stuck. You should at least have the skeleton of the trigger in place as that's easy to find in the standard documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger leadCampaignManager on Lead (after insert) {
    Map<String, Id> campaigns = new Map<String, Id>();
    CampaignMember[] cms = new CampaignMember[0];
    for(Lead record:Trigger.new)
        campaigns.put(record.CustomField__c,null);
    for(Campaign record:[SELECT Id, CustomValue__c FROM Campaign WHERE CustomValue__c in :campaigns.keyset()])
        campaigns.put(record.CustomValue__c, record.Id);
    for(Lead record:Trigger.new)
        if(campaigns.contains(record.CustomField__c))
            cms.add(new CampaignMember(LeadId=record.Id,CampaignId=campaigns.get(record.CustomField__c),MemberStatus='Sent'));
    insert cms;
}
```

Your specific needs will vary, but this general approach should work. Replace `CustomValue__c` and `CustomField__c` as appropriate; the rest of the code should work verbatim.

---

**Update**

```
trigger leadCampaignManager on Lead (after insert) {
    CampaignMember[] cms = new CampaignMember[0];
    for(Lead record:Trigger.new)
        if(!String.isBlank(record.CustomField__c)) {
            cms.add(new CampaignMember(LeadId=record.Id,CampaignId=campaigns.get(record.CustomField__c),MemberStatus='Sent'));
    insert cms;
}
```

Assuming we already have a campaign ID, we don't need to query the database; we can just insert it directly.

However, this being said, you could also use the `Campaign` field available when creating leads. This is available in the UI and for Web to Lead.

**Edit 2**

---

For Web to Lead, use the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Campaign_ID" value="701000000000000" />
```

Change the ID value to match the campaign you'd like to use.

Comment: Thanks! Can I set it so that it adds the lead to a specific campaign, where it will get the campaign ID from the custom field?

Comment: Updated answer. Also note that there is a *standard feature* that does this as well, so you may not need code.